# Disable checkbox when no checkboxes on page

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm trying to disable the checkbox when there are no rows inside.

I tried something with checkbox: disable... but doesn't matter.

```
 function addRow(tableID) {
     var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
     var rowCount = table.rows.length;
     var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
     var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
     var element1 = document.createElement("input");
     element1.type = "checkbox";
     element1.name = "chkbox[]";
     cell1.appendChild(element1);
     var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
     cell2.innerHTML = rowCount;
     var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
     cell3.innerHTML = rowCount;
     var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
     cell4.innerHTML = rowCount;
     var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
     cell5.innerHTML = rowCount;
     var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
     cell6.innerHTML = rowCount;
 }

 function deleteRow(tableID) {
   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;

   for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
     var row = table.rows[i];
     var chkbox = row.cells[0].children[0];
     if (chkbox != null && chkbox.checked == true) {
       table.deleteRow(i);
       rowCount--;
       i--;
     }
   }
   var rootChkbox = table.rows[0].cells[0].children[0];
   if (rowCount == 1) rootChkbox.checked = false;
 }

 function checkAll() {
     var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   var val = null;
     for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
         if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
             if (val === null) val = checkboxes[i].checked;
             checkboxes[i].checked = val;
         }
     }
 }
```

Hope you guys can help me!

**[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/SDpTT/)**

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: Please read [ask], and include a [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third party site.

Comment: @HenkErtje I don't see where you are trying to disable the checkbox?...

Comment: When there are no rows in the table. The checkbox must be disabled.

Comment: 1) disable it by default. 2) enable it when add row. 3) disable it after delete row if only 1 row.

Comment: Would be helpful to post the html here or put all of your code in the stack overflow code snippet. That way, any answer isn't having to reference content hidden behind a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this in your delete function:

```
if (rowCount == 1) rootChkbox.checked = false;
```

To:

```
if (rowCount == 1)
{
    rootChkbox.checked = false;
    rootChkbox.disabled = true;
}
```

And add this to your add Function:

```
if (rowCount == 1)
{
    rootChkbox.disabled = false;
}
```

Full Code:

```js
 function addRow(tableID) {
     var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
     var rowCount = table.rows.length;
     var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
     var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
     var element1 = document.createElement("input");
     element1.type = "checkbox";
     element1.name = "chkbox[]";
     cell1.appendChild(element1);
     var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
     cell2.innerHTML = rowCount;
     var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
     cell3.innerHTML = rowCount;
     var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
     cell4.innerHTML = rowCount;
     var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
     cell5.innerHTML = rowCount;
     var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
     cell6.innerHTML = rowCount;
     var rootChkbox = table.rows[0].cells[0].children[0];
  if (rowCount == 1)
     {
         rootChkbox.disabled = false;
     }
 }

 function deleteRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
   var row = table.rows[i];
   var chkbox = row.cells[0].children[0];
   if (chkbox != null && chkbox.checked == true) {
    table.deleteRow(i);
    rowCount--;
    i--;
   }
  }
  var rootChkbox = table.rows[0].cells[0].children[0];
  if (rowCount == 1)
     {
         rootChkbox.checked = false;
         rootChkbox.disabled = true;
     }
 }

 function checkAll() {
     var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var val = null;
     for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
         if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
             if (val === null) val = checkboxes[i].checked;
             checkboxes[i].checked = val;
         }
     }
 }
```

```css
body {
    font: 14px/18px Arial;
 padding: 30px 20px;
 background: gray;
}

table#dataTable {
    margin-top: 10px;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
<table id="dataTable" cellPadding="5" cellSpacing="0" border="1" rules="all">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" onchange="checkAll()" name="chk[]" disabled="disabled"/>
        </th>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Start Year</th>
        <th>End Year</th>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help! Please accept the answer and upvote it if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
if(checkboxes.length == 1) { checkboxes[0].setAttribute('disabled','disabled');}
```

You can further segment your selection by looking for a parent element:

```
<div id="group1"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
<div id="group2"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
```

Then the JS would look like this

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("#group1 input[type=checkbox]");
```

Hope that helps.